# Facing difficulty with javascript getelementbyid

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

If some one have any suggestion or other way kindly help.
I have

- 1 `Textbox`
- 1 `Label`
- 1 `LinkButton`

when I'll click to `lnk_NameEdit` button `txtUserName` will visible and `lblusername` buttons must unvisible and the text in lable will display in `TextBox`

```
<td width="237" class="value_td" style="border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #afc0f3;">
      <asp:Label ID="lblusername" runat="server" Text="Santosh"></asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Width="300" Visible = "false">    
      </asp:TextBox>
</td>


<td width="64" class="epotions_td" style="border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #afc0f3;">
   <span>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_NameEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" OnClientClick = 'ControlVisible();'>Edit</asp:LinkButton>
   </span>|
</td>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function ControlVisible() {

         var lbl = document.getElementById("<%= lblusername.ClientID %>");
         var txt = document.getElementById("<%= txtUserName.ClientID %>");        

         lbl.visible = false;         
         txt.visible = true;
     }
</script>


<td width="237" class="value_td" style="border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #afc0f3;">
      <asp:Label ID="lblusername" runat="server" Text="Santosh"></asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Width="300" Visible = "false">    
      </asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

and I have 1 `LinkButton`

```
<td width="64" class="epotions_td" style="border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #afc0f3;">
   <span>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_NameEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" OnClientClick = 'ControlVisible();'>Edit</asp:LinkButton>
   </span>|
</td>
```

when I'll click to `lnk_NameEdit` button `txtUserName` will visible and `lblusername` buttons must unvisible and the text in lable will display in TextBox

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function ControlVisible() {

     var lbl = document.getElementById("<%= lblusername.ClientID %>");
     var txt = document.getElementById("<%= txtUserName.ClientID %>");        

     lbl.visible = false;         
     txt.visible = true;
 }
```

Comment: You can also use Jquery Instead. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
lbl.style.visibility="visible";         
txt.style.visibility="hidden";
```

Comment: it is showing "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required" Error... in txt.style.visibility="hidden";

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of the code is correct, `lbl` and `txt` will be dom elements.  Dom elements do not have visible properties, but you can hide them by setting their styles' display properties:

```
lbl.style.display = "none";
```

**EDIT**

Make sure you run this code after your **dom is ready**.  That you were getting null from document.getElementById probably means that you were running this script right in your `head` section.  As a result, your dom had not yet been parsed, and your label and textbox didn't exist yet.

The easiest way to fix this is to put the script section at the very end of your body.  Another way would be to call `ControlVisible` from your body's onload:  `<body onload="ControlVisible()">`

Comment: thanx for your Reply... I have already tried but is shows the Error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object" Thst is in "txt.visible = true;" this line....

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between server executed code and client side code.
In the moment you have a mix.

You can set the visibility of an element in client side (javascript) setting the display property
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom3.shtml

You can change this piece og code from this:

```
lbl.visible = false;         
txt.visible = true;
```

to this:

```
lbl.style.display= "none";         
txt.style.display= "block";
```

If you are working with server side code (e.g Load event, asp. net button click, etc) you can use the visible property of your object.

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WzTSR/

Answer (score 0):

Your Textbox with ID `txtUserName` has `Visible = "false"` which means **it's not being sent to the browser**  - thus you get client side error.

Change this to:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Width="300" style="display: none;">
```

Which will still make it invisible by default, then change the lines to:

```
lbl.style.display = "none";
txt.style.display = "";
```